# jQuery Fader with Variable Delays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a fade in/out jQuery sequence (similar to below) but the boss wants to be able to specify different display times for a few of the lines. I haven't had much luck playing with it.

```
function ShowList() {
  var i = 1;
  function showQt() {
    if (i === 1) $('li').hide();
    $('li').eq(i - 1).fadeIn(500, function() {
     $('li').eq(i - 1).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function() {
        if (++i > 4) i = 1;
        showQt();
     });
    });
  }
  showQt();
}
ShowList();
```

What I need to do is customize the delay(1000) for individual li elements. So each displays for 1 second by default per above, but how would I modify this if I wanted only li #3 to display for 5 seconds, for example?

Is this even possible?

[I've added a simplified jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/smdfiddle/ytxe0b9k/3/) - includes the suggested timer array, but that's not working either.

Thanks for any help.

**Square brackets, of course. Thanks guys. Fixing that almost worked, but was then stuck with the timers cycling through as if we were one short (though had 4 for 4 lines). [Added an extra item to beginning of array](http://jsfiddle.net/smdfiddle/ytxe0b9k/5/) so now have 5 timers for 4 lines (guess the first one is ignored?) but now we're golden.**

Comment: please add a jsfiddle

Comment: Create an array called `timers` with 10 elements and as you cycle through the `li` elements, assign the duration from the `timers` array..
`var timers = (2500,2500,2500,5000,2500,8000,2500,2500,2500,2500);`

Comment: @chanie - Looking at your Fiddle, you need to put your array in `[]` brackets... so like this: `var timers = [1000,1000,5000,1000];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var timers = [1000,1000,1000,5000,1000,8000,1000,1000,1000,1000];
// Sorry about my terrible array notation!

function ShowList() {
  var i = 1;
  function showQt() {
    var d = timers[i-1];
    if (i == 1) $('#textFade li').hide().delay(d);
    $('ul#textFade li').eq(i-1).delay(d).fadeIn(1000, function() {
      $('ul#textFade li').eq(i-1).delay(d).fadeOut(500, function() {
        if (++i > 10) i = 1;
        showQt();
      });
    });
  }
  showQt();
}
ShowList();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/cL7ku6yL/)

Comment: Thanks for responding. This doesn't seem to be working either... I've added a jsfiddle to the original post if you're still willing to take a look.

Comment: @chanie My mistake, fix the `timers` array notation and it will work!

Comment: Awesome. For some reason I had to add an extra timer to the beginning of the array for this to work properly, but at least we got there. Much obliged!

Comment: Because, in Javascript, indexes starts at 0, not 1.